How to receive a JWT token in the body of an API response from a server and save it on the user with javascript and react-18?
enter image description hereI have a mongo DB server which an API set up when you input a proper username and password it sends a JWT access token in the body of the response as shown in the picture it works. (takes an email and password to verify)
I'm building a front-end application now to post an authentication request which is working fine, However what i want to do is store the body of the response in a cookie with a key of x-auth-toekn to be sent in the body of all api requests. Chat gpt spit this out which says it saves the response in a cookie however in dev tools application tab i see nothing saved.
front end code is as follows and i'm receiving the api payload's response but it's not being stored. I want to be able to reuse the token (will figure out refresh tokens later fyi)
import React, { useState } from "react";

const LoginForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://myapi.com/api/auth", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to login");
      }

      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      const authToken = jsonResponse["x-auth-token"];

      if (authToken) {
        // Save token in cookie
        document.cookie = `authToken=${authToken}; path=/`;

        // Alternatively, save token in local storage
        // localStorage.setItem('authToken', authToken);

        setToken(authToken);
        console.log("Token:", authToken);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Token not found in response");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login Error:", error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login Form</h2>
      {token ? (
        <p>Logged in! Token: {token}</p>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              name="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;

Picture showing the JWT is arriving from my API in the body of the response, i assume it's json but it has no parenthesis in the response.

The token is a JWT which is a base64 encoded JSON.  Paste it into https://jwt.io to quickly see what it contains.  But you shouldn't be creating your own storage for this.  JWT's need to be verified and normally expire after a few minutes - now you'll need to deal with validating and renewing the token.  I personally use react-oidc in my React apps though there are tons of other choices.  It's not 100% clear that your environment is OIDC compliant but, again, be careful with trying to create your own.

I built the backend with a course so it has an auth middleware to decode and calls jwt.verify then returns to req.user. I've tested it with postman and it's working minus the token expiring, but the payload is showing the _id and iat of the user like expected on JWT.io. I'll look into react-oidc as it seems like a better long term solution, but all verification occurs on the api side when a request is made. In the meantime i'm okay with the token expiring and needing to be logged in every 15 mins for testing purposes while i build up the app.

I found the answer, it's just
document.cookie = `x-auth-token=${response.data}`;

